# How to open a file from service_worker on Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a Chrome extension that reads an Excel file from Explorer and writes data into the file.

**Manifest**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Menu scraper",
    "description": "Scrapes menu information and downloads a zip file containing an Excel file on menu information and menu image files",
    "version": "0.2",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://www.foodpanda.my/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "exceljs.min.js",
                "jszip.min.js",
                "FileSaver.min.js",
                "scraper.js",
                "export.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://www.foodpanda.my/",
        "https://images.deliveryhero.io/"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "contextMenus",
        "downloads",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
importScripts('./exceljs.min.js')
importScripts("./jszip.min.js")
importScripts("./scraper.js")
importScripts("./export.js")

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id": "scrape_addons",
    "title": "Add choices for current menu item",
    "documentUrlPatterns": ["*://www.foodpanda.my/restaurant/*"],
    "contexts": ["all"]
})

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async (clickData) => {
    if (clickData.menuItemId == "scrape_addons") {
        /*Code to open file dialog to load Excel file before running web scraping script*/
        
        chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
            function(tabs) {
                /*Code to run web scraping in webpage*/
            }
        );
        
    }
})
```

I would like to have the extension to select the Excel file to read and write to in `service_worker` before executing the web scraping script as it involves validating certain attributes (e.g. matching food vendor name) before running the script. Using `showOpenFilePicker()` in the background script doesn't work as `window` is undefined in the background script:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Is it possible to open the file dialog from the `service_worker` script (e.g. by selecting a `contextMenu` option) of a Chrome extension without having to enter `chrome.scripting.executeScript` (which could not use the libraries imported on the `service_worker`-side) to create an `input` element to use the file dialog?

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I have added context that the dialog has to be opened in a `service_worker` script. With `window` being undefined, is it possible to access `showOpenFilePicker()` in a background script?

Comment: Posting your code and any errors it causes increases your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I have added the code for the manifest and background script, as well as why `showOpenFilePicker()` does not work in the background script.

Comment: See [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).

Comment: I don't think the file dialog can be displayed without going through the UI. Create a tab or window by clicking on the context menu and display the file dialog via it.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Seems that the only option to open the file dialog from a background script is to use `chrome.scripting.executeScript` to run the open file dialog script in the tab. Is it possible to read the file (in this case, an Excel file using the Exceljs library shown in the manifest) that was passed back to the background script-side from the open file dialog script in the tab?

Comment: I think it's never a valid option, but that doesn't stop you from trying it.